# export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH causes libncurses.5.4.dylib not loaded error

Tags: macos, osx-lion, ncurses, dyld

On my **OS X 10.7.4** Mac I do:

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

But afterwards I get this sort of errors:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /bin/ls
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ls requires version 5.4.0 or later, but libncurses.5.4.dylib provides version 5.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

To alleviate this problem, I've built the `libncurses.5.4.dylib` from scratch and installed it into the `/usr/local/ncurses-5.9` and did:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib_BACKUP
sudo ln -s =/usr/local/ncurses-5.9/lib/libncursesw.5.4.dylib /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
```

This newly built libncurses works fine but as soon as I do

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

it returns the same `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib`

*As a comparison*: When I do the same `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on my **OS X 10.5.6** Mac, it gives no error whatsoever. So I think it should work my **OS X 10.7.4** Mac, too.

What should I do to make it work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ops! When I checked the `/usr/local/lib` directory, I've found that there were `libncurses.dylib` files there and  because the exported `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` was loading them and they were obviously not binary compatible with the system, I was getting the error.

After I deleted those obselete `libncurses.dylib` files under `/usr/local/lib` the error is gone. Problem solved.